# Generic type methods shortcut

Tags: c#, methods, properties

I recently wrote a logger class which gets initialized in my `IoC`.

```
public static class IoC() {
    public static ILogger Logger => IoC.Get<ILogger>();
    [...]
}
```

`ILogger` has generic type method:

```
void Log<T>(string message, LogLevel level = LogLevel.Info);
```

So that I could maintain my logs better.

I'm able to call it like:

```
IoC.Logger.Log<GeneralLog>("My message");
```

Now, that is pretty long line.

Is there a possibility in C#, so that I could declare a shortcut for the `Log<T>()` method with pre-defined generic type?

For example:

Instead of

```
IoC.Logger.Log<GeneralLog>("My message");
```

I could write

```
IoC.Logger.General("Message"); // and this should reference to IoC.Logger.Log<GeneralLog>
```

Comment: What have you tried, when tyring to implement this new method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IoC.Logger` is of type `ILogger`, which presumably is outside your control, so you can't edit it to add that method.

You could write it as an extension method though:

```
public static class ILoggerExtensions
{
    public static void General(this ILogger logger, string message)
    {
        logger.Log<GeneralLog>(message);
    }
}
```

Now you can call `.General(string)` on each `ILogger`, such as the one returned by `IoC.Logger`.